# Base methods/operators return base type when called on derived (C++)?

Tags: c++, inheritance, typing

Given:

```
class Base:
{
  public:
  ...
  Base operator+( const Base& other );
  Base& scale( float num );
}

class Derived : public Base:
{
  public:
  ...
  Derived( const Base& other );
  float super_math_wizardry();
}

//A user can do the following:

Base b1,b2,b3;
Derived d1,d2,d3;

b3 = b1 + b2;
d3 = d1 + d2;

b3 = b1.scale( 2.0f );
d3 = d1.scale( 3.0f ); //scale returns Base& type that is converted to Derived

float x,y;

x = (d1+d2).super_math_wizardry(); //compiler type error since d1+d2 returns Base type
y = (d1.scale(4.0f)).super_math_wizardry(); //similar compiler error

x = Derived(d1+d2).super_math_wizardry(); //works
y = Derived(d1.scale(4.0f)).super_math_wizardry(); //works
```

Is there a way to make the first two statements work without re-implementing every Base method in Derived (make Derived methods that call Base methods and returns Derived types) and without requiring the user to make casts/call copy constructors?

EDIT: All Derived objects are in the set of Base objects (as is needed for the class inheritance), but not all Base objects are in the set of Derived objects.  They have the same data members, but a Derived object has a constant value assigned to one of those data members (the same constant value for all Derived objects).

There are many methods that are Base or Derived specific, but most of the operators and set/get accessors have the same defined behavior on Base and Derived objects. The thing I'm trying to do is get a Derived or Derived& back when I call a Base method on a Derived object (since these operations are mathematically defined to do so), while still getting a Base or a Base& when calling a Base method on a Base object.

CONTEXT: Base is a Matrix class and Derived is a Vector (column) class.  The Derived( const Base& other ) constructor was made for explicitly getting a Vector from a single column (nx1) Matrix.

So I want:

```
x = (d1+d2).super_math_wizardry(); //works
y = (b1+b2).super_math_wizardry(); //fails (although possibly at run-time since a nx1 Matrix is a column vector)
```

Comment: Irrelevant nitpick: are you sure `scale` should return a reference?

Comment: @SteveJessop why not?? scale could "return *this" to avoid copying.

Comment: @Matthais: ah, silly me, I didn't consider that `scale` might be a mutator. My new irrelevant nitpick is that `operator+` should be a `const` member function!

Comment: I take it that suggesting `template <typename T> float super_math_wizardry(const T &t) { return Derived(t).super_math_wizardry(); }` wouldn't be welcome, because there are actually lots these derived functions, so you don't want a lot of boilerplate for each one any more than you want a lot of boilerplate for each function in `Base`? But the fact that `Derived` has a `Base` constructor is unusual. It suggests to me that `Derived` adds no data members, and hence that you could define `super_math_wizardry` as a free function rather than a member function to begin with, and get rid of `Derived`.

Comment: I made some edits to make it more clear what I'm looking for and to provide some context.

Comment: If the only problem is to make Base::operator+ return a Derived type, then you can make use of the so-called "curiously recurring template pattern". Or you provide a global template operator+ that can be limited by SFINAE to your own classes. Both are advanced template programming techniques. It wouldn't make you code nicer or better maintainable, though, I guess. (If anyone's interested, I can provide an example.)

Comment: @DyP: I was considering suggesting CRTP in my answer, but as far as I can see the questioner only has one base class and one derived class. So using CRTP would actually *increase* the amount of boilerplate. If there were lots of derived classes then it would probably help. Same probably goes for the free `operator+` template, except that I didn't already think of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your context, I think the fundamental problem you have is informing the compiler that the set of `Derived` objects is closed under `operator+`. I know it, you know it, but there's no special shortcut in the C++ language to express it. You do need to implement `Derived Derived::operator+(const Derived&) const`.

I'd probably make the `Derived(const Base &other)` constructor `explicit`. Presumably it throws an exception if the dimensions of `other` are wrong, so it's not something that users should expect to happen implicitly. They need to know it's right, so they might as well have to say that they want it to happen.

Comment: That is a bummer as in my application I'm worried about code coverage so this will nearly double my test cases.  I thank all of you for all of your help.

Comment: @user1445306: well, maybe you could cheat your test methodology a bit. Change `for case in cases {assert(case.left + case.right == case.result)}` to `for case in cases { assert(case.left + case.right == case.result); if (case.result.cols == 1) assert(Derived(case.left) + Derived(case.right) == Derived(case.result);}`. Then your line coverage metric will tell you whether your test cases actually include any single-column matrices, which is probably worth knowing even if there *was* some clever way of doing what you want. Yeah, it's testing two code units in parallel, not just one. Sue me ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Well the short answer is, no.

The functions have a return type of Base. What you are asking the compiler to do is no different than doing

```
Derived d1;
Base* b = &d1;
b->super_math_wizardry(); // This is also wrong since we don't know that b can be
                          // a derived class
```

There is simply no way to do this because there is no way for the language to know the difference between the above and

```
Base* b1 = new Base();
b1->super_math_wizardry(); // This is just plain wrong
```